# Laravel Horizon deployed via Google App Engine, processes do not start

Tags: laravel, google-app-engine, laravel-horizon

I am having trouble starting the processes/queues for a job server deployed to Google App Engine. In the Horizon dashboard, the instance names are visible, but no processes show and jobs do not execute.

[image]

While running the code on my localhost, processes/queues do start and execute jobs. I confirmed that the `horizon.php` config is correct and matches my `APP_ENV`, yet still, no processes start.

Any guidance is appreciated!

Comment: You comment that you managed to deploy your application to App Engine. Did you follow steps like those described [here?](https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/run-laravel-on-appengine-flexible), This is from a purely Laravel to App Engine perspective as I am not familiar with Horizon myself.

Comment: Yes, I have the app working. The only thing that is not working is Horizon is not starting the queues/processes. I'm almost certain that I can update my supervisord.conf file to run the jobs using `php artisan queue:work --queue=high,default` but would like to take advantage of Horizons dashboard if possible.

Comment: I'm glad to hear that the application is working. As I said before, I am not familiar with Laravel Horizon, so I'm sorry I cannot help you further on that side. I am sure there is someone here who can give you the help you need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Horizon opens and closes php processes with the `proc_open` and `proc_close` functions which are on the list of permanently disabled functions in Google App Engine. After adding these to the `whitelist_functions` configuration under the `runtime_config` in the `app.yaml` everything works great.

Comment: Hey @johnnyg17, could you please show what is the syntax to add this configuration. ```whitelist_funtions: proc_open,proc_close``` is what i tried using as the GAE docs says it needs to be a list of comma separated functions and the default is empty string. Still does not work. Kindly help!